# Getting "Unable to instantiate application" for MainApplication.kt after upgrading React Native and migrating from Java to Kotlin on Android

Tags: java, react-native, kotlin

I have recently upgraded my React Native app to version 0.73.0 which also includes switching from Java to Kotlin for MainActivity and MainApplication classes.

Now when I try to run the app, I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application xxx.xxx.xxx.MainApplication package xxx.xxx.xxx: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "xxx.xxx.xxx.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Since the question has been closed I'll answer here in a comment:
Be sure you have made all the necessary changes that were suggested by the Upgrade Helper (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper).
To be 100% sure you've done everything right, do the following:
1. Download a folder comparison application (eg. Beyond Compare)
2. Create a new RN project: `npx react-native@latest init MyTestApp`
3. Check every file by hand with Beyond Compare for differences and amend any you deem necessary.

This helped me fix some issues that I left out or incorrectly copied. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

OK. After spending a couple of hours I finally figured out how to fix this. This is not mentioned in React Native 0.73.0 upgrade documentation.

So, in order to get the project working, you need to take the following steps after your actual RN upgrade:

1. Open your project-level `build.gradle` and add include `kotlinVersion = '1.9.0'`
2. Add `google()` in the `buildscript.repositories` and `allprojects` in the same `build.gralde` file.
3. Add `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${project.ext.kotlinVersion}"` in the `dependencies`.
4. Do a `Sync`.
5. open up the `build.grdle` file inside the `app` folder and add `apply plugin: "kotlin-android"` at the top of the file.
6. In the dependencies section add the following dependency: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"`.
7. Do a `Sync`.

Now your project will run correctly.

Comment: I've run onto the same problem from the exact same reasons, I've tried to follow your solution and I keep getting:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

Just to make sure I've done all the steps correctly. Did you replace rndiff's app implementation of classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin") with this classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${project.ext.kotlinVersion}"

Comment: And is this the correct implementation?
allprojects{
    repositories {
          google()
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

After some additional testing today, I've found out that my issue is something with the new Kotlin files (MainActivity, MainApplication).

I've followed the React Native Upgrade Helper file by file since the npx upgrade failed, and what I've noticed is that my application will build successfully agaon once I revert the file extensions to .java instead of .kt. Even though I've updated the code inside the both files from RN Upgrade Helper, with the minimal custom code (in my case for Bootsplash screen and RN Screens).

This should be the temporary solution only, because the main change of this version is switching to Kotlin for Android, we should see how the next minor version can affect this.

**EDIT SOLVED:**

Finally found out what was the issue in my case. The problem was caused by MainApplication.kt and MainActivity.kt files, I didn't update these files correctly.
I followed the raw files content from RN Upgrade Helper and adjusted this content with my implementation and my Android app has finally built successfully.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.73.0/RnDiffApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/rndiffapp/MainActivity.kt

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/release/0.73.0/RnDiffApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/rndiffapp/MainApplication.kt